# Hardcoded dependency injection container itself?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I understand that generally lets not store object reference but get it from a container:

original code:

```
class Mail
{
    public $subject, $mailer;

    public function __construct($mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $this->mailer->send($this);
    }
}


class Mailer
{
    public function send(Mail $mail)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Rewritten with DI:

```
class Mail
{
    public $subject;

    public function send()
    {
        DI::get('mailer')->send($this);
    }
}

class Mailer
{
    public function send(Mail $mail)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

besides code became shorter, now its not way to bring this code to different framework. Lets say this DI was implement by Zend, and now this code cant be used under Symfony. In other words dependency container itself hardcoded.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Is "how I reuse code strongly coupled with another framework/library?" your question?

Comment: in kind, yes. Everybody say "use DI". Thats the 2nd codeblock. But then, DI itself is coupled to the code, it cannot be moved to other project. First codeblock is almost framework independent

Comment: Actually, the first snippet is correct DI pattern implementation. The second is called service locator which is a bad pattern. Therefore using DI **container** doesn't mean you're following DI pattern.

Comment: its still hard to decide when to use what. Why bad pattern? Much easier to mock it